# non SGML character number 6

Tags: php, html, validation, codeigniter, sgml

I am getting the following validation error for a site I am working on

```
 Line 1, Column 1: non SGML character number 6

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.…
```

And in FireFox source viewer, the text is red for the following lines

```
DOCTYPE
HEAD
META CHARSET
/HEAD
BODY
2 Paragraph tags (that are properly opened and closed.
```

When I use the web developer FireFox addon, and choose the "Edit HTML" option, there is a red dot, and all the tags up to `<title>` disappears. There is also no body tag, and the same two paragraph tags that are shown red in FireFox source viewer is also gone. In other words, the red means errors of some sort, but I see no errors whatsoever in the source.

Here it is shown, the parts that indicate as errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>

</head>
<body class="page">

<p>
    <div class="photo-box photo-box-right" id="photo-box-test-image-619">
        <div class="photo-box-photo">
            <img src="http://localhost/assets/uploads/images/logo.png" title="Test image" alt="Test image" />
        </div>
        <div class="photo-box-title">
            <span class="photo-box-head" title="Test image">Test image</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    Qualitative data approximates, characterizes or describes but does not measure the attributes, characteristics, properties of a phenomenon.  Data could take the form of textual transcriptions of interviews, focus groups or dialogues, photographs, audio and video recordings.
</p>
<p>
    <div class="photo-box photo-box-left" id="photo-box-test-image-476">
        <div class="photo-box-photo">
            <img src="http://localhost/assets/uploads/images/sparta.jpg" title="Test image" alt="Test image" />
        </div>
        <div class="photo-box-title">
            <span class="photo-box-head" title="Test image">Test image</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    Quantitative data defines attributes in terms of values with numerical significance and can be represented as matrixes of numbers of responses, maps, tables or graphs.
</p>
```

I can not see any errors in the HTML. I see no hidden control characters in any normal editor that I can get my hands on (Notepad++, UltraEdit, Notepad, Wordpad) but I do see it in the "Edit HTML" screen of the Web Developer toolbar.

Here is what I have done to try and resolve this:

1. Recreate the file and retyping the supposed affected lines.
2. Used various text editors to try and see the wrong file.
3. Removed all recently added content and code in the file to see if this stops at any point (no luck...)
4. Read all the posts I can find about "non-SGML character" I could find here and on Google, nothing seem to answer my question.
5. Deleted the post in the database and recreated that (for incase this is a problem with database content). Not resolved.
6. Converted all tables to MyISAM (some, including the content table, were InnoDB)
7. Checked if other pages that does not draw its content from the database has the same problem (such as contact form) and it does the same.
8. Played around with various character sets and encodings in my database and HTML source, as well as my PHP ini file. None affect the outcome.
9. Changed the code page in all my text editors to various types to try and see this hidden non-SGML character.
10. Copied all the system and application files (excluding the obvious changes such as CSS and templates and modified modules) over from another site based on the same version of CodeIgniter that works well.

Anything else you think I can do?

From the above, I conclude that either the custom modules (unlikely), the CSS stylesheets, the added jQuery libraries that are different between the sites (uniform.js, buttons.js) or the templates and views used is having some sort of pukefest on my happiness.

Please advise if you can think of something else I have missed...

Thanks!

Kobus

EDIT: Now that I am allowed to add images, I decided to make a few screenshots to explain the problem better. Maybe it helps... I initially thought it may be the whitespace in the title tag, but wasn't that...[image: Screenshot 1][image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: `<p>` elements cannot contain block level elements. They are paragraphs. Also, all of those divs are probably better as a `figure`, `figcaption`, and `img` tags, if you can move to HTML5. Example: https://gist.github.com/3844490

Comment: Thank you @Madara Uchiha. I will investigate this. Problem that I do see is that the `<p>` tag is automatically added by CKEDITOR. So, in the CMS you only see `[[image:1:left]]Paragraph content here.` and not `<p>[[image:1:left]]Paragraph content here</p>` which means that my end users will not be able to place the image place holders correctly. I will investigate if I can get this done regardless, as it is the best way forward (perhaps edit the image replacement code to do the replacement before the `<p>` tags. This will not help the contact form though - there are no divs inside p tags there

Comment: @Madara Found out something else... If I copy the text from the FireFox source view, and paste it in my text editor, I get this: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">` (which is, of course, notshown here, grrrr... but shown in my editor as a `-`.

Comment: And you're saying retyping didn't solve it? Did you try retyping in a different editor?

Comment: Hi @Madara, yes, retyping didn't solve. But... I didn't retype in a different editor. I will do that now and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Just retyped in normal Windows Notepad. Not solving. I didn't retype the entire template though, just the parts that were shown in red in FireFox's source viewer that indicates a problem. The template is a 300 line template for Code Igniter with mixed HTML and PHP in it, called template.php.

Comment: @Madara, I retyped now in notepad as well as notepad++, and not having any luck. I want to thank you for your help so far. Please let me know if you can think of anything else? Kobus

Comment: @Madara, now added screenshots so that you can see the result of this hideous non-SGML character. I can simply not ignore it...

Comment: Post an HTML document (or a URL for one) that demonstrates the problem. The code snippet does *not* do that. (It has other markup errors, but not this one.)

Comment: Hi @JukkaK.Korpela, The site is on my localhost, which you can not access via URL. I will have to upload the entire site to my host, or just the template.php file. I will make a plan... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi everyone who responded,

Thank you so much for all your efforts to help, in particularly @MadaraUchiha for their patience and effort.

The problem was eventually solved after I have uploaded the site to my web hosting space (thanks @JukkaK.Korpela who suggested this), and tried to access the page. On my local dev environment, the CodeIgniter error screen does not display (will have to figure out why) but on my hosting space, I got a clear indication of what the error was:

`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /usr/www/users/imperoco/demo/application/helpers/bootstrap_helper.php:1)`

In another file (a CodeIgniter helper file) there was a - in front of the `<?php` tag. So - somehow, when I was editing it, I must've added a rogue -. Removed it, and now the page displays fine.

Thank you so much for your time. Now that I know my development environment does not display the error, I can work to resolve that, to prevent issues such as this the next time around. :-)

Kind regards,

Kobus

Answer (score 0):

It may be an encoding issue.  Make sure that the file is saved as ANSI or UTF8 *WITHOUT* the BOM marker.  The BOM marker may cause this issue.

In Notepad++, the fourth menu is for encoding, you can easily change this there.

Comment: Hi @Jahmic. Thank you for your reply. I tried what you said - opened the file in Notepad++, set the encoding to UTF8 without BOM, and saved the file. Still the same problem.

Comment: hi @Jahmic. I have now added screenshots so that you can see the result of this hideous non-SGML character. I can simply not ignore it...